# Common elements in 2 different arrays

Tags: java

I'm making a basic coding algorithm that takes an input, codes it (using random numbers), then decrypts. The arrays are filled with type "char". It encrypts each letter individually. How can I check that when it is coding a letter, that the same letter hasn't been encoded as something else.

Example

encoding

abc

a is given random number 2
b is given random number 5
how can i prevent c being given 2 or 5

Thanks alot!

Comment: If you're using random numbers from 1 to 26 to represent characters, just generate a list of 1 to 26 and shuffle it, instead of generating each number randomly and checking if it's already been used.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström this should be an answer.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström This might lack a bit of randomness as this is for encryption (you always encrypt with a shuffled array of numbers between 1 and 26).

Comment: @MarvinLabs: True, but that's a point you should make to John, not to me, which is hugely overshadowed by the fact that he should **not** try to invent his own encryption.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström :) I agree totally with that. I guessed he was doing that for fun or learning anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is my proposition:

```
    Character yourInput[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
    int yourInputEncoded[] = new int[yourInput.length];
    Hashtable<Character, Integer> charToInt = new Hashtable<Character, Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> alreadyUsedInt = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Random randomize = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i < yourInput.length; i++)
    {
        if(!charToInt.containsKey(yourInput[i]))
        {
            int randomInt = randomize.nextInt();
            while(!alreadyUsedInt.contains(randomInt))
                randomInt = randomize.nextInt();

            charToInt.put(yourInput[i], randomInt);
            alreadyUsedInt.add(randomInt);
        }
        yourInputEncoded[i] = charToInt.get(yourInput[i]);
    }
```

For each char, we check is there associated to int. If not we generate (randomly) a new associated int (which has been never used before).
After that we replace the char by his associated int. That it :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Baz would work but would be slow (relatively speaking, as you need to search the set for each generated number but you might not care).

The answer from Christoffer Hammarström (generate N consecutive numbers and shuffle) works but lacks randomness as this is for encryption.

Here is an algorithm to get an array of unique (almost) random numbers.

1. Determine how many different characters you need to be able to encode (caracterSetCount)
2. Allocate an int array of `caracterSetCount` size
3. Generate random numbers to use later:

static final int RANDOM_RANGE = 3000;

```
randomKeys = new long[caracterSetCount];
randomKeys[0] = rand.nextInt(RANDOM_RANGE); // A number between 0 and RANDOM_RANGE 
for (int i=1; i<caracterSetCount; ++i) {
  randomKeys[i] = randomKeys[i-1] + 1 + rand.nextInt(RANDOM_RANGE); 
  We have a pseudo random number which is strictly greater than the previous one
}
```

1. If needed, you can shuffle that list (as it is ordered, you might want to improve)

You then have an array to get pseudo-random numbers from for each character to encode.

To get more randomness, you could increase RANDOM_RANGE (but take care that you don't overflow as you keep adding numbers);